# tensorflowjs compatible version for tf==1.15 for tf_saved_model to tfjs conversion

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter, tensorflow1.15

I have trained one object detection model in tensorflow.

My Environment:

tf version == 1.15,  network== ssd mobilnet v2

Now i want to convert my saved_model(.pb) file to tfjs(.json) format.

I followed below steps--

```
pip install tensorflowjs==0.8.6 # not sure if it's compatible with tf version 1.15
```

command:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_format=tfjs_graph_model --signature_name=serving_default --saved_model_tags=serve exported_path/saved_model exported_path/web_model_path
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'keras_applications' has no attribute 'set_keras_submodules'
```

Then i degrade keras_application version.

Now getting error as

```
usage: TensorFlow.js model converters. [-h]
                                       [--input_format {keras,tf_session_bundle,keras_saved_model,tf_hub,tf_saved_model,tensorflowjs,tf_frozen_model}]
                                       [--output_format {keras,tensorflowjs}]
                                       [--output_node_names OUTPUT_NODE_NAMES]
                                       [--signature_name SIGNATURE_NAME]
                                       [--saved_model_tags SAVED_MODEL_TAGS]
                                       [--quantization_bytes {1,2}]
                                       [--split_weights_by_layer] [--version]
                                       [--skip_op_check SKIP_OP_CHECK]
                                       [--strip_debug_ops STRIP_DEBUG_OPS]
                                       [--output_json OUTPUT_JSON]
                                       [input_path] [output_path]
TensorFlow.js model converters.: error: argument --output_format: invalid choice: 'tfjs_graph_model' (choose from 'keras', 'tensorflowjs')
```

So there is no option for tf_graph_model in output_format.

Now when i am installing pip install tensorflowjs  (not passing any specific version), then it installs tfjs==3.3.0, and uninstaling my current tf1.15 and installing new tf2.x version. which i need to avoid at any cost.

How to convert the saved_model to tf_js format in version tensorflow==1.15.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please upgrade  tensorflow to latest version tf 2.x, stable versions tf 2.6/2.7 and let us know if this issue exist as tf 1.x is not supported any more and hence these errors.